Column Decryption in BigQuery
I have a table in BigQuery, in which 1 column ssn is encrypted using .
I am doing encryption from Nifi using vault and the algorithm used is AES256, such that the encryption key in the format "sdfdfsASgfdsHsaDSFSjsdasfsfblaBlaBLAsdfdfsASgfdsHsaDSFSjsdasfsfblaBlaBLAsdfdfsASgfdsHsaDSFSjsdasfsfblaBlaBLAsdfdfsASgfdsHsaDSFSjsdasfsfblaBlaBLA=" .
The encrypted column is in the the format "blablaBLABlaBLaBlA+xUErvXADaYg=".
Then encrypted column is stored in a BigQuery table.
I am looking for a way to decrypt this column from the BigQuery console using the same key.
Tried the solution mentioned here and here and customized the query to be:
SELECT AEAD.DECRYPT_STRING(KEYS.ADD_KEY_FROM_RAW_BYTES(b'', 'AES_CBC_PKCS', b'sdfdfsASgfdsHsaDSFSjsdasfsfblaBlaBLAsdfdfsASgfdsHsaDSFSjsdasfsfblaBlaBLAsdfdfsASgfdsHsaDSFSjsdasfsfblaBlaBLAsdfdfsASgfdsHsaDSFSjsdasfsfblaBlaBLA='), CAST(ssn AS BYTES), '') AS plaintext FROM `vf-grp-maml-dev-lab-01.Test_Dataset.test_table`;

Then i got the below error in the BQ console:
Failed to add a key from raw bytes: Unsupported key size: 404 bytes; expected 16, 24, or 32 bytes.; error in KEYS.ADD_KEY_FROM_RAW_BYTES expression

I have also tried to write the query in the below format:
WITH EncryptedInput AS (
  SELECT FROM_BASE64('blablaBLABlaBLaBlA+xUErvXADaYg=') as ciphertext,
    FROM_HEX('sdfdfsASgfdsHsaDSFSjsdasfsfblaBlaBLAsdfdfsASgfdsHsaDSFSjsdasfsfblaBlaBLAsdfdfsASgfdsHsaDSFSjsdasfsfblaBlaBLAsdfdfsASgfdsHsaDSFSjsdasfsfblaBlaBLA=') AS key
)
SELECT AEAD.DECRYPT_STRING(KEYS.ADD_KEY_FROM_RAW_BYTES(b'', 'AES_CBC_PKCS', key), ciphertext, '') AS plaintext
FROM EncryptedInput;

But also got the below error:
Failed to decode invalid hexadecimal string due to character at offset 1: sdfdfsASgfdsHsaDSFSjsdasfsfblaBlaBLAsdfdfsASgfdsHsaDSFSjsdasfsfblaBlaBLAsdfdfsASgfdsHsaDSFSjsdasfsfblaBlaBLAsdfdfsASgfdsHsaDSFSjsdasfsfblaBlaBLA=

Can you please guide me how to properly formulate the query to decrypt the ssn column.

Hi @Noura, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.

The issue was fixed by using the keyset key json and the function DETERMINISTIC_DECRYPT_STRING
